# How can I set up Visual Studio to understand GCC defines?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a project in C and in a header file is defined the following code,

```
/*_INLINE_ define for abstraction of the keyword inline*/
#define INLINE    __inline__
```

I have compiled the project with the GCC for a Tricore microcontroller, now I have to compile the same project witn Visual Studio 2010 for the simulation.

But the Visual Studio Compiler shows the following error:

```
error C2054: expected '(' to follow '__inline__'
```

How can I set up the Visual Studio to understand this define ?

Answer (score 3):

`__inline__` is a [GCC-specific keyword](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html#Alternate-Keywords), not a macro. What you will have to do is find out the MSVC equivalent of that keyword, and change the contents of the macro `INLINE` based on which compiler is running.

[MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88(v=vs.100).aspx) seem to indicate the MSVC rendition of the keyword would be `__inline`. Therefore, you should modify your header like this:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
  #define INLINE __inline__
#elif defined _MSC_VER
  #define INLINE __inline
#else
  // Some kind of default, or error out
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, the C Code is autogenerated,  It would be better to have a solution like a Compiler flag.

Comment: @poprock The sole (or at least *main*) purpose of using a macro like `INLINE` instead of the keyword directly is to allow the actual contents of the macro to vary without affecting the code using it. I'd look into ways of modifying *that*, first.